# Nesting Structs in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm a noob at C and need some help getting my code to...welll...do anything. I have the following put into a .h file.

```
typedef struct
{
    int active; 
    int dead;
    ucontext_t t;
    struct node *link;
}gtthread_t;

struct node{
   struct gtthread_t thread;
};

typedef struct
{
int rubic;
}gtthread_mutex_t;
```

This is in a .h file... a .h file where I have had to #include ucontext.h ... which I know I am also not supposed to do... but it's the only way I can access ucontext_t, I find.

So, my error here is "field thread has incomplete type".

Why? What does that even mean? And how can I possible NOT import ucontext.h if I want to declare structs with that kind of data in the .h file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has nothing to do with your other include. This has to do with the fact that your first struct is anonymous and has a type name `gtthread_t`. C unlike C++ distinguishes between `gtthread_t` and `struct gtthread_t`.

Either name the struct:

```
struct gtthread_t
{
    int active; 
    int dead;
    ucontext_t t;
    struct node *link;
};
```

Or change the type name to the typedef:

```
struct node{
   gtthread_t thread;
};
```

Comment: Woooww... didn't realize it distinguishes between those two. I've opted to change the typename to the typedef. Riddle me this, though - how would I access node to thread to thread's data? node->thread->active? For example?

Comment: since `thread` is not a pointer you would access it like `node->thread.active` (assuming `node` is a pointer to `struct node`). In C `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`

Answer (score 1):

The [`ucontext.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ucontext.h.html#tag_000_010_219) header only pre-declares the `ucontext_t` type. You're only supposed to use *pointers* to it, since its size is not known. Change your code to:

```
ucontext_t *t;
```

and you will be fine. Notice that all the functions in the `ucontext.h` header use such pointers to refer to contexts. This is common in C API design, since it allows the representation to be hidden inside the API's implementation, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `struct node` has not been declared yet, so the `gtthread_t` type cannot be completed.

```
typedef struct
{
    int active; 
    int dead;
    ucontext_t t;
    struct node *link;        
}gtthread_t;

struct node{
   struct gtthread_t thread;
};
```

You'll need a forward declaration of `struct node`:

```
struct node;

typedef struct
{
    int active; 
    int dead;
    ucontext_t t;
    struct node *link;        
}gtthread_t;

struct node{
   struct gtthread_t thread;
};
```

Try that and see if it makes a difference.